# How To Sort An Array List

Tags: c#

There are 2 listboxes to exchange items. Each list item has text and value properties
eg: "Branch",1 ; "Leaves",23,...etc
After adding an item from listbox2 to listbox1, I would like to sort listbox1.

lb1 and lb2 are the listboxes.

```
protected void btnRemove_Click()
{
  if(lb2.Items.count > 0)
   {
     if(lb2.selectedindex >=0)
      {
        ListItem li = lb2.selecteditem;
        lb1.items.add(li);

        //sort
         List<ListItem> al = new List<ListItem>();
         foreach(listitem l in lb1.items)
          {
           al.Add(l);
          }
        lb1.items.clear();
        al.sort();
        lb1.Datasource=al;
        lb1.databind();
     }
   }
}
```

At `al.sort();` it gives an error - "Failed to compare 2 elements in the array".
How should I correct this.

Comment: The code you've given wouldn't even compile (C# is case-sensitive) and we don't know what `lb2` and `lb1` are. Additionally, is there any reason you're using `ArrayList` rather than `List<T>`?

Comment: They are the names of the listboxes. No reason. I was just trying out omerkamal's suggestion - http://forums.asp.net/t/1094374.aspx

Comment: That's a suggestion from 6 1/2 years ago... back when some people were still unfortunately on .NET 1.1. There's very little reason not to use generic collections now...

Comment: That article is six years old! Be very careful about the age of articles on the Internet.

Comment: @jonskeet, I tried using List, but the same error at sort. could you plz check

Comment: We still don't know what's in the listboxes, and you still haven't provided code which would even compile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your existing code is that you are adding `ListItem` in `ArrayList` and to sort the `ArrayList` should contain objects which implements `IComparer` as stated in [How can i sort Arraylist with a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076307/how-can-i-sort-arraylist-with-a-class)
You can add a custom `IComparer`something like this,

```
public class MyListItemComparer : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
        //ListItem item1 = (ListItem)x;
        //ListItem item2 = (ListItem)y;
        return 1;//Your logic to compare and sort;
    }
}
```

and then you can call the `sort` method as

```
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        ..... //Your other code
        IComparer myComparer = new MyListItemComparer();
        al.Sort(myComparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to sort ur `al` array:

```
al.OrderBy(a => a);
```

Comment: It did not error at this line now, but did at 'Databind(); - "Listitem does not contain property formname' But I have DataTextfield="formname" Datavaluefield="formid"...same for both listboxes

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your array list contains the correct data and its not null.
`al.sort();` should work on arraylist of integers,string and other datatype if they inherit `IComparable` else you need to write your own comparer.

Comment: which namespace. I have system.collections and generics but i dont get collections...

Comment: it sure doesnt have nulls, each listitem has a string and int value

Comment: have u tried parsing items to string `al.Add(lb1.items[i].toString());`

Comment: yes. It did not error sort now, but did at 'Databind(); - "Listitem does not contain property formname' But I have DataTextfield="formname" Datavaluefield="formid"...same for both listboxes